# biggest rally data collection

Tags: data, market-data, historical-data

Where can I find data for biggest rally(price rally) in a day? If this sort of information is not readily available, how could I produce/transform such data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good old Wikipedia:
Here is a list of largest one day gains on the Dow Jones. I also think they have a list for the S&P 500

[largest one day gains](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_daily_changes_in_the_Dow_Jones_Industrial_Average)

Comment: I am looking for such data on daily basis with the ticker. For e.g. I would like to know the biggest rally for today once the market closes.

Comment: Oh I see. Perhaps try finviz and screen for those stocks with largest daily gains... I just searched for largest gainers today: http://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=ta_perf_dup&ft=3&o=-change